# Does node package.json support alpha or beta meta range according to SemVer?

Tags: node.js, versioning, package.json, semantic-versioning

There is [the official documentation about package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) but I didn't find any mention about meta tags like alpha, beta, etc.

For example in PHP Composer I can set `^2.0@beta` and it will imply more or equal `2.0` and less than `3.0` including beta and higher (alpha not included).

So, I'm looking for the expression `including beta and higher`.

Is there something similar in node `package.json` file?